# Half the circuits on a Pro/tran 2 transfer switch do not work on generator

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Installed a Pro/Tran 2 6 circuit transfer switch.  The switch works fine on "Line".  However, the circuits on A, C, and E do not work on "GEN". The circuits on B, C, and F work on both Line and Gen. Does anyone have any ideas of why the circuits on A, C, and E do not work when transfer switch is in the generator mode?
The model number on the transfer switch is A306.  The generator is an ECOFlow 3600wh solar generator.  It is connected to the transfer switch by a 30 amp line.

Comment: Is your generator (unspecified) a 120V or a 120/240V type? Sounds like the sort of problem you'll have with a 120V generator hooked to a panel expecting 240V, so one phase is dead. But since you give no details about your setup, had to be sure.

Comment: More description on the model number of the generator and the way you have connected things are necessary. As it is, only guesses can be made. My guess based on alternate circuits working: only one side of the generator is connected and/or the generator is only 120V, not 240V split phase.

Comment: Also, please clarify: Circuit C is listed as working and not working. Is one of those supposed to be a D?

Comment: What kind of a main panel do you have? Picture would help. An interlock + generator inlet would give you a lot more flexibility, possibly for not much more money than the transfer switch, though it depends on your panel situation (I needed to replace *everything* in order to get that interlock. But then again, I would have need to have done an awful lot to put in a transfer switch too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a "generator" - it does not convert fuel or motion or solar energy into electricity. It is a giant battery backup. But more importantly, it only has 120V output. Connect it somehow to a 120V/240V split-bus panel and you will either power all the 120V circuits but none of the 240V circuits (though they may get a little confused because controls, lights, motors might work but heating elements won't) or, as is the case stated by OP, **half** the 120V circuits.

Why? By design. With a grand total of 3600 Wh of energy storage, that's (assuming perfect conversion, but close enough) 120V x 30A for one hour, 120V x 15A for two hours, 120V x 7.5A for four hours, etc. If it *could* handle 240V, it would at best give you 240V x 20A for 45 minutes. And 240V @ 20A is about as low as 240V circuits typically go. So there is no real point in supporting 240V output, and given that there is no point in providing the second hot wire needed for a split-bus transfer switch to work properly.

Options:

- You *may* be able to wire things up so that both hots on the transfer switch feed from the single hot on the so-called generator. That will make things work, but it won't increase the runtime.
- Get a real generator.

A big battery backup is great for controlled circumstances - e.g., job site, camping, etc. where you have a known load and a fairly well-defined runtime. For a partial home backup in an outage (typically weather related in the US), that just doesn't work. If the outage is expected to be 4 hours or less, just wait it out - your refrigerator will be OK and everything else is no big deal. But if the outage turns into 12 hours or more, 3600 Wh just isn't going to last very long. A regular generator is big and noisy, but actually a lot cheaper than one of these battery backups and can run a typical house indefinitely, with the exception of dryer, oven, cooktop, water heater and HVAC. Actually HVAC usually isn't too bad as long as it doesn't involve resistance heat.

Don't confuse 3600 Wh (3600 W for one hour) with 3600 W continuous (which even a small generator can do just fine - for example, here is a [Westinghouse from Home Depot rated at 3600 W for less than $400](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Westinghouse-WGen3600cv-4-650-3-600-Watt-Gasoline-Powered-RV-Ready-Portable-Generator-with-Recoil-Start-and-CO-Sensor-WGen3600cv/318060962)). A 6000 W to 8000 W generator can handle even the typical big 240V loads (dryer, oven, cooktop, water heater, HVAC) if managed well (i.e., one at a time) and plenty are available in the $600 to $1,000 price range. Compared to a battery backup where $1,000 will get you less than 2,000 Wh - and when the battery is dead, that's it.

Comment: Why the downvote? Somebody doesn't like that my answer isn't eco-friendly? When the power goes out you can rough it or you can have a system that works. Spending $3,000+ on a battery backup and transfer switch and then cursing when the battery runs out after a few hours is not my idea of fun.

Comment: I don't like the "get a real generator" comment, even though I like those solar generators far, far less...... for how they prey on ignorant rich people.  (hey I can get a fully packaged lithium battery pack *at the Nissan dealer parts counter* for 25 cents a watt-hour. 62 kWH pack for a Leaf. so over $1/Wh is inexcusable.)  Unfortunately my friend I am not your downvoter.

Comment: Where there is a "solar generator" that **includes solar panels** I would consider that a "generator". As far as I can tell, most of these Eco Flow "generators", especially the larger ones, do **not** include solar panels. That is the key. Whether electricity is *generated* from sun, wind, gas, hydro, etc. doesn't matter. (It does, but not for this terminology discussion.) But this is **not** a generator. It is a **storage battery** that can be charged from a number of different sources and discharged as needed.

Comment: The problem I see is those solar panels they offer are weak tea e.g. 400W at best.  I have another question elsewhere where the guy has two Jackery type things and wants to power up his house and get the house solar panels producing and recharging his Jackeries and I'm like /cringe ... the worst part is he could have afforded a PowerWall before buying the Jackeries and costly accessories.

Comment: The downvote fairy never tells, in my experience, so it's generally best to ignore them. Actual defects in the answer will normally be commented, and may be downvoted if egregious enough, and DVs will be removed or reversed if incorrect things are edited to correctness. None of that applies to the downvote fairy...

Comment: @ecnerwal really. A few years ago, your DV would've been because with the wrong iOS version, the upvote button active area is the size of the button, but the downvote active area was the full height of the answer.

Comment: On the Eco Flow 3600 that I found in a quick search, they *recommend* 4 x 400W solar panels. Which (if correct, and of course depends on full sunlight, etc.) is 1600W and can charge this box up in 3 hours. But they don't include the solar panels. So as is, it is a battery backup box, not a generator. Bundle it and then you can call it a generator. Crazy.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the skill to be responsible with energy use... the root of your problem is that the US is not a 120V country.  It's a 240V country, delivering 240V as two "poles" or "legs" of 120V. Technology Connections [has a snarky-fun but very accessible video about that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4).

So your 120V Jackery is delivering power to only one pole of your 120/240V service.

The panel would need to be examined internally to see whether it would be wise to deliver power to both legs; *the issue being shared-neutral Multi-Wire Branch Circuits (MWBCs)*.  Or circuits could be rearranged (taking special care around MWBCs) so all your critical loads are on the same pole.